# Populate to join two collection in Mongodb gets null data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create an API in node to get nearby users with the same pet_type.

UPDATE: After Reading the first answer and as per the documentation. I update my user model and I Tried using populate but it doesn't get me all the pets data of the user.

User Model

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  password: String,
  first_name: String,
  email: String,
  location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: []
  },
  pets: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, 
    ref:'Pet', default:null
  }

});
```

Pet Model

```
var PetSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  pet_type: String,
  breed: String,
  owner_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User', default:null},
});
```

Current Query

```
    var lat = req.query.lat;
    var lng = req.query.lng;
   
    User.find({
        location: {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [lng, lat]
                },
                $maxDistance: 10000
            }
        },
        _id:{ $nin :req.decoded._id }}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({success:false, message:"No listing found", error:err});
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({success:true, message:"User found", data:users});
            return;
        }
    }).populate('pets');
```

output

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Pet data",
    "data": [
        {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    72.53808,
                    23.02622
                ]
            },
            "pets": null,
            "_id": "5f32cb544f6b1a07acd75f48",
            "phone": "1234567890",
            "email": "qwewqe@qwe.com",
            "first_name": "qwertt",
       
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .populate() method

Comment: Thanks for helping populate did solve the problem also this article is helpful https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
`You can use lookup (aggregation) in mongodb`

link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

link : https://www.isummation.com/blog/perform-inner-join-in-mongodb-using-lookup-aggregation-operator/